# What Order to Deploy .NET Application with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, deployment, setup-deployment

I have created an Windows application.

I used

FRONT END : C# (VISUAL STUDIO 2008)
BACK END  : MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2008
.NET FRAMEWORK : 3.5

Now after deployment when I am installing the application in my Clients machine is it necessary to first install .Net Framework, VisualStudio2008  and Sql Server 2008 before installing Application?

And in which module of building my set up file(FileSystem Editor, Registry editor etc..) should I attach the DataBase?

This is my first application of deployment so please help me out with tips and tracks for deployment?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You customer will not use Visual Studio, so you don't need to install it.

You will need to install SQL Server manually. You cannot have your setup project install it automatically. Just install SQL Server 2008 (SP1 or higher). I believe this will install all or most of .NET 3.5 for you. If not, then when your setup is run, it will install any other parts of .NET that are needed.

BTW, be sure to test the installation steps on a clean system of your own (maybe on Virtual PC) before trying it on your customer's site!

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
Please give me some tips to test the application on my own. Since this is my first project I am tensed!!!
Please help me out!!1

Comment: Just pretend you're the customer. Take the installation documentation you were going to give the customer, and perform all the steps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want every client to have SqlServer installed locally (usually, on an Enterprise scenario, you have already a server box with Sql Server running, and you just need to deploy your database there). 
If having Sql Server running locally is a requirement, you might want to take a look at this thread which will help you: [How to install a custom desktop application database to SQL Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978146/how-to-install-a-custom-desktop-application-database-to-sqlexpress)

Answer (score 0):

You should install SQL Server manually before installing your application.

You just need to install you application, you do not need visual studio. If you use a setup project to do this it should detect that it requires the .Net framework and give the user the option of installing it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install the Visual Studio. For running .Net applications, you only require .Net Framework. And for SQL 2008 also .Net required. And for Database, either you have to run SQL Script or you may need to restore the database. Running SQL Script is better I think, you can do it via a Batch file.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a batch file?